# Basic Array Error in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn arrays and I can not figure out this code. For some reason when I run this an error is identified, but the entire code is highlighted as the error so I am confused as to where the error really is. I know this is very basic, but any help would be very appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x[8];
    for (int i =0; i<= 8; i++)
        x[i] = i;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i<8 will fix that. 01234567 -> 8 digits.

Comment: More explicitly, in `int x[8];` the 8 becomes the number of elements, and their valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7.  You try to write to `x[8]` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x[8];
    for (int i =0; i<8; i++)
        x[i] = i;
    return 0;

}
```

Because arrays start at 0 accessing array index 8 is to far as that is actually slot 9.

Comment: _"Arrays start at 0 not 1"_ The OP's sample starts with `0` correctly, but missed getting the upper bound correctly.